# Firebase Login Assertion failed: new_time >= loop->time, file c:\ws\deps\uv\src\win\core.c, line 309

Tags: windows, firebase, assertion, firebase-tools

I got a new Surface Laptop 3.  I typically use a MAC but need windows for a few things.  I have been using parallels but decided to bite bullet and get real windows machine.

I use firebase and got firebase-tools installed and running fine.  But when I tried to login (using `firebase login` for the CLI, I keep getting the error message as shown above: `Assertion failed: new_time >= loop->time, file c:\ws\deps\uv\src\win\core.c, line 309`.  I have used bash and powershell with same result.  I also logged into a cmd prompt as administrator.

I have searched and searched and found a few things related to the clock and checked that.  I also ran some filesystem checks etc.  But nothing works.  It all works OK in my Windows 10 envioronment under parallels on my MAC but this new laptop cant deal.

Can someone point me in the correct direction?

Comment: I also just updated the firmware (5/31/2020) for my surface laptop 3 and I get the same error

Answer (score 5):

Looks like its an Ice Lake, Nodejs conflict of some sort.  I was having this problem for months with my new HP spectre x360.

Seems it's been patched a few days ago in node: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1772

I just updated my node install to 12.18.0 (I was on 12.16.1) and I'm no longer getting the error when I attempt firebase cli commands.  Hopefully a node update will work for you as well: https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Comment: Wow.  Thanks - I will try that when I get home

Comment: I'm getting this error on my new HP spectre x360 when running using webpack - I've tried everything including installing node 11, 12, 13, and 14 - currnetly on node 12.18.3 and still have the error.

google only shows resutls related to firebase, but I'm experiencing it using a build process with laravel mix and npm scripts.

Answer (score 1):

### **Update the Node!!!**

in my case it was v14.4.0 and it was throwing the same error

```
new_time >= loop->time, file c:\ws\deps\uv\src\win\core.c, line 309
```

and i updated the node to v14.8.0 and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

for vm virtualbox win 10
I had the same issue on Windows 10. I simply synchronized the clock.

1. shut down Windows not restart
2. start vm (Windows)
3. go to clock settings "DATE & time"
4. set button called "Set time automatically" to on
5. set button called "Set time zone automatically" to on
6. There is a button called "Synchronize Your Clock" -> click button "Sync now"
   And the issue got resolved

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. After a loooooong search, I decided to try with WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux). Once it finished, I installed node and firebase tools using it.

That is the only way that I found to solve this problem. Hope this will be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my Windows10 x64 machine (Surface Pro 7) with one of my NodeJs projects. I've installed the latest surface pro fireware update (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=100419) and updated to latest NodeJS 14.11.x Version (https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/).

now it works :)